# Bootstrap 3 centered active image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

[image]

I'm trying to modify the Boostrap 3 carousel to look like this. This is what I did so far:

```
<div class="tcarouselcont">
    <div id="tcarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item" data-b="1">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1140x500/ff9320&text=1">
            </div>
            <div class="item active" data-b="2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1140x500/c6363c&text=2">
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-b="3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1140x500/647291&text=3">
            </div>
        </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#tcarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#tcarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>                
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#tcarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#tcarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#tcarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>

.tcarouselcont
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

#tcarousel > .carousel-inner
{
    width: 999999px;    
}

#tcarousel > .carousel-inner > .item
{
    width: 1140px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#tcarousel > .carousel-inner > .item:nth-child(1)
{
    margin-left: -750px;
}
```

I've got the layout, but it's not working as I want it to work. The slider should occupy the 100% percent of the screen width and the .item wit .active class should always be in the center (so, on the next transition [3] should be in place of [2] and so on). The other two images should occupy the rest of the space (if any) evenly.

Any help is appreciated and welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go with an approach like this..

### http://bootply.com/108301

It uses jQuery to move the appropriate slides into the `active` item.